# Replace a 'Title' tag with a Custom Field

Tags: customization, title

I have this code in my theme:

```
<div class="article-navigation">
                    <?php previous_post_link('<div class="navigation-item  navigation-item--previous">%link</div>', 
                                sprintf('<span class="arrow"></span>
                                        <div class="navigation-item__content">
                                            <div class="navigation-item__wrapper">
                                                <span class="button-title">%s</span>
                                                <h3 class="post-title">%%title</h3>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>', 
                                __('Previous Article', 'border_txtd')) ); ?>

                    <?php next_post_link('<div class="navigation-item  navigation-item--next">%link</div>', 
                                sprintf('<span class="arrow"></span>
                                        <div class="navigation-item__content">
                                            <div class="navigation-item__wrapper">
                                                <span class="button-title">%s</span>
                                                <h3 class="post-title">%%title</h3>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>',
                                __('Next Article', 'border_txtd')) ); ?>
                </div>
```

I want the 'Previous' and the 'Next' buttons to pull a Custom Field called 'HTML_title' instead of the regular 'Title'.

Thank you.

Comment: That `sprintf( '%%title' )` won't work. Also the function is missing the second string.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to read up on `get_post_meta()`.  Here is a link to the [WP Codex reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) for that function.

`<?php $meta_values = get_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $single ); ?>`

If you created that custom field with something like Elliot Condon's ACF plugin, the documentation for the plug-in is also helpful in meeting your exact need.

Assuming you are inside the loop so something like this should produce what you want:

```
$key_title = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'yourkeyname', true );
echo $key_title;
```